# Can multiple portlets share a singleton?

Tags: java, singleton, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

Is there a way to create a Singleton instance of an object across portlets but running on a single JVM? Already tried creating singleton class via static synchronized access of the object but still the instance is singleton but per each portlets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your Singleton look like?

Comment: refer to the answer that this is marked as duplicate to. Variations apply if you're *not* using different web applications.